# How to define input variable when datalines have spaces for a variable

Tags: input, sas, dataset

I want to have two different strings in the same dataset.
I tried to separate valeus with "" but it didnt work. Imagine I dont want to write "" but only strings inside. I searched a lot but did not find anything related to.
Could you guys please help me to get my goal?

```
data ecl.dim_produtos;
   input id_produt id_departament id_order id_business id_portfolio initials $4. long_name $40. short_name $30.;
   datalines;
    1 1 10201 4 1 PZC "Puzzle Crédito" "Puzzle Crédito" 
    2 1 10202 4 1 PZR "Puzzle Reestruturados" "Reestruturados"
    3 2 10207 30 1 DBO "Banca Online" "Banca Online"
    4 3 10210 60 1 CLB "Colaboradores" "Colaboradores"
    5 1 10203 4 1 PZF "Puzzle Formação" "Code Academy"
    6 4 10205 5 1 HIP "Hipoteca Inversa" "Hip. Inversa"
    7 5 10206 25 1 EMP "DEMP" "DEMP"
    8 6 10208 45 1 NCO "NewCo" "NewCo"
    9 6 10211 70 1 LDRC "Lendrock" "Lendrock"
    10 4 10209 50 1 OTI "Otima Provision" "Otima"
    11 6 10001 1 1 LDC "Lendico" "Lendico"
    12 6 10007 1 1 MIBL "Market Invoice BL - EUR" "Market Invoice BL"
    13 6 10003 1 1 CRS "CreditShelf" "CreditShelf"
    14 6 10005 1 1 FUN "Funding Circle" "Funding Circle"
    15 6 10002 1 1 RAI "Raize" "Raize"
    16 4 10204 5 1 FLX "Flex" "Flex"
    17 6 10101 2 1 AUX "Auxmoney" "Auxmoney"
    18 6 10009 2 1 UPG "Upgrade - EUR" "Upgrade"
    19 6 10104 2 1 PRO "Prodigy Finance" "Prodigy"
    20 6 10102 2 1 FEL "Fellow Finance" "Fellow"
    21 6 10008 1 1 ASZ "Assetz - EUR" "Assetz"
    22 6 10010 2 1 LDB "Lendable - EUR" "Lendable"
    23 6 10004 1 1 LIN "Linked Finance" "Linked"
    24 6 10103 2 1 LDR "Lendrock" "Lendrock"
    25 6 10105 3 1 EDX "Edebex" "Edebex"
    26 6 10006 1 1 CAM "Camomille - FC" "Camomille"
    27 6 10106 3 1 MIN "Market Invoice - EUR" "Market Invoice"
    90 0 99991 102 2 DIV "Dívida Pública - EUR" "Dívida Pública"
    91 6 99992 103 2 CRP "Obrigações Corporate - EUR" "Obrigações Corporate"
    92 0 99990 101 3 SDA "Disp. Aplicações OIC - EUR" "Disp. Aplicações OIC"
    9999 0 999999 999 99 TOT "Total Patrimonial - EUR" "Total Patrimonial"
;
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most reliable approach would be to:

- define the variables of the `INPUT` statement using a `length` or `attrib` statement.
- use `INFILE` options to specify how the data lines are parsed by `INPUT`
- take the `$` out of the `INPUT` statement

Example (leave data lines as-is):

```
length 
  id_produt id_departament id_order id_business id_portfolio 8
  initials $4
  long_name $40
  short_name $30
;
infile cards dsd dlm=" ";
```

For the case of wanting data lines with double quotes, you will have to modify the data lines to separate the values with two or more spaces and use the `&` argument for the variables in a list-style `INPUT` statement.

You could also separate the values in the data lines with a `tab` character and use `DLM='09'x`.  You might have some trouble seeing and entering tabs using the SAS editor.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure to use the `:` modifier if you want to include informat specifications in the INPUT statement to avoid switching between list and formatted input modes.

If you can insure that you have have at least two spaces between the values (and that the values themselves do NOT have adjacent spaces inside them) you can use the `&` modifier.

```
data test;
   input id_produt id_departament id_order id_business id_portfolio
         initials &:$4. long_name &:$40. short_name &:$30. 
   ;
datalines;
1 1 10201 4 1 PZC  Puzzle Crédito  Puzzle Crédito 
2 1 10202 4 1 PZR  Puzzle Reestruturados  Reestruturados
;
```

Or keep the quotes and make sure there is exactly one space between each value (**and don't indent the datalines!**) and add the DSD option.

```
data test;
   infile datalines dsd dlm=' ' truncover ;
   input id_produt id_departament id_order id_business id_portfolio
         initials :$4. long_name :$40. short_name :$30. 
   ;
datalines;
1 1 10201 4 1 PZC "Puzzle Crédito" "Puzzle Crédito"
2 1 10202 4 1 PZR "Puzzle Reestruturados" "Reestruturados"
;
```

Or use a different delimiter, with or without the DSD option.

```
data test;
   infile datalines dsd dlm='|' truncover ;
   input id_produt id_departament id_order id_business id_portfolio
         initials :$4. long_name :$40. short_name :$30. 
   ;
datalines;
1|1|10201|4|1|PZC|Puzzle Crédito|Puzzle Crédito
2|1|10202|4|1|PZR|Puzzle Reestruturados|Reestruturados
;
```